# Can Miraluka 'see' droids?

Tags: star-wars

The Miraluka see via the force, which makes up for their blindness. They cannot see creatures like the Yuzhan Vong.

My question is can they see droids?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe they can. Non-living things are still in/part of the Force, that's why Jedi can manipulate them with the Force. Recall that in RotJ, Luke lifted C3PO, which means he could sense him, which means the Miraluka can probably sense him and other droids too.

Comment: +1: Miraluka can still "see" walls and other obstacles well enough to not go around bumping into them all the time, so droids shouldn't be much different.

Comment: In b4 Midi-Chlorians!

Comment: If this is the case, they should actually be able to see the Yuzhan Vong in the sense of seeing the emptiness where otherwise a force presence would be. It'd be like a blank spot in their vision.